# Redirect "ugly" URL to new URL using htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have already rewritten my old "ugly" URL:

```
http://example.com/ppd-brands/generic/?gen_id=Mjky
```

to

```
http://example.com/ppd-brands/generic/gen_id/Mjky
```

using the code below

```
RewriteRule ^ppd-brands/generic/gen_id/([^/]*)$ /ppd-brands/generic/?gen_id=$1 [L]
```

and it's working.

Now my problem is how can I *redirect* the old "ugly" URL to the new URL when the user visits the old "ugly" URL?

Answer (score 0):

```
Redirect 301 /oldurl.htm /newurl.htm
```

change old and new URL according to your need. Hope it helps you

Comment: my code: `RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^ppd-brands/generic/gen_id/([^/]*)$ /ppd-brands/generic/?gen_id=$1 [L]
  Redirect 302 /ppd-brands/generic/?gen_id=Mjky /ppd-brands/generic/gen_id/Mjky`

Comment: RewriteEngine On RewriteRule ^ppd-brands/generic/gen_id/([^/]*)$ /ppd-brands/generic/?gen_id=$1 [L, R=301]

Comment: the code you give is working but it`s only redirect in old url  when i visit the new url. vice versa is not working.

Comment: RewriteEngine On RewriteRule ^ppd-brands/generic/gen_id/([^/]*)$ /ppd-brands/generic/?gen_id=$1 [R=301, L]

Comment: You can't use a mod_alias `Redirect` to perform this type of redirect. **1)** You can't grab the query string URL parameter using a `Redirect`, which is required here. **2)** You will likely need a _condition_ to prevent a redirect loop, because of the existing rewrite. `Redirect` does not allow you to create conditions - you need to use mod_rewrite for this.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^ppd-brands/generic/gen_id/([^/]*)$ /ppd-brands/generic/?gen_id=$1 [L]
> ```

Just a precursor... whilst your old "ugly" URL was of the form `/ppd-brands/generic/?gen_id=Mjky`, you should ideally be *rewriting* to the actual file that handles the request, eg. `index.php`, instead of allowing mod_dir to issue an additional internal subrequest to the directory index - which is what I assume is happening here.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^ppd-brands/generic/gen_id/([^/]*)$ /ppd-brands/generic/index.php?gen_id=$1 [L]
```

Now, your main question... to externally redirect from the old "ugly" URL to the new URL. In this case, you need to be careful of a redirect loop, since if we simply redirect then the above rewrite will rewrite it back again in an endless loop. You can't use a mod_alias `Redirect` (as the other answer suggests) for this reason. (And a mod_alias `Redirect` can't match the query string either - another reason.)

*Aside:* Since we changed the above rewrite to include `index.php` in the rewritten URL, which would appear to differ from the old "ugly" URL, we could perhaps get away with a simple redirect if you are on Apache 2.4 (but Apache 2.2 would result in a conflict because mod_dir would issue an internal subrequest for `index.php` *before* we can process the URL with mod_rewrite).

We need to only redirect initial requests, not requests that we have already rewritten. We can do this by checking against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable, which is *empty* on the initial request and set to "200" (as in `200 OK` HTTP status) after the first successful rewrite. (Another way is to check against `THE_REQUEST`, instead of the dynamic/rewritable URL-path.)

For example, try the following *before* your existing rewrite:

```
# Redirect "old" to "new"
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^gen_id=([^/&]*)
RewriteRule ^(ppd-brands/generic)/(?:index\.php)?$ /$1/gen_id/%1 [QSD,R=302,L]
```

Note that in order to match the query string we need a condition (`RewriteCond` directive) that checks against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable. The URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* notably excludes the query string.

The `index.php` in the request URL is optional, so it matches `/ppd-brands/generic/?gen_id=Mjky` or `/ppd-brands/generic/index.php?gen_id=Mjky` (if that is the actual URL).

The `$1` backreference is simply to save typing/duplication. This will always contain `ppd-brands/generic` when the directive matches. We could have done the same with "gen_id", but that could make the *susbstitution* string look a bit too cryptic.

The `%1` backreference (note the `%` prefix) is a backreference to the captured group in the last matched *CondPattern* (as opposed to `$1` which refers to the `RewriteRule` *pattern*), ie. the value of the `gen_id` URL parameter.

The `QSD` flag (Apache 2.4+) strips the query string from the redirected URL. Otherwise `gen_id=XYZ` would be passed through to the target URL. If you are still on Apache 2.2 then you would need to append a `?` to the end of the *substitution* string instead (essentially an empty query string). eg. `/$1/gen_id/%1?`

The "magic" is really the first condition that checks the `REDIRECT_STATUS` env var. As mentioned above, this ensures that we only process initial requests and not the rewritten request, thus avoiding redirect loop.

Note that this is currently a 302 (temporary) redirect. Only change to a 301 (permanent) once you have tested this works OK. 301s are cached persistently by the browser so can make testing problematic.

And just to clarify... a redirect like this should only be implemented once you have already changed all the URLs in your application. This redirect is to simply redirect search engines, backlinks and anyone who should manually type the URL (unlikely).